# Calculate average time to empty the router

Tags: markov-chains, queueing-theory

Consider a buffer, in which every second the number of packets increases 
by 1 with probability $.4$ and decreases by 1 with probability $.6$. 
Currently there are $n$ packets in the router. 
Calculate the expected amount of time to empty the buffer.

Comment: It's not a good idea to alter your question once it has been answered. If you want to ask a new question, you should do that separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A formal argument:** Consider a random walk on the integers that jumps to the left
with probability $q$ and to the right with probability $p$ where 
$p+q=1$ and $q>p$.

Let $e$ be the expected number of jumps to hit the state 
 to the left of the starting position. First step analysis 
says that 
$e=1+p(e+e)$, so that $e=1/(1-2p)$.

The expected number of steps to hit state 0 starting at $n$ is 
therefore $n/(1-2p)$. For $p=.4$, this gives the answer $5n$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: For every sample, you decrease an average of 0.2 samples (ie: After 10 samples, 4 will add and 6 will subtract, will leave you 2 samples lower).  When would you reach 0 in average?

Comment: Thank you, but i am a bit confused. After 10 second the router will have n-2 packets, so i want to be n-n=0 packets to be empty. So?

Comment: If you have 1 packet, it will take 5 seconds to empty. If you have 2 packets it will take 10 seconds to empty.  Can you put this into a general equation?

Comment: So in general, if i have n packets i will need 5n seconds to empty the router, right?And is this the  average time?

Comment: Yes! That is the average time.

Comment: Thank you very much! So no type, no markov, no queueing system, nothing?Thank you!

Comment: You can state this in a Markov Chain and should end up with the same result.